# Adobe AIR - Unable to build a valid certificate chain for the signer

Tags: apache-flex, air, certificate

I purchased a p12 certificate but am having difficulty using it. I always get the following error when trying to sign my app:

*Error creating AIR file: Unable to build a valid certificate chain for the signer.*

[image: screenshot]

**This is not an issue when I sign the app with a self-signed certificate.**

I'm trying to sign a .air file for the desktop. I'm on Mac OSX. Is there anything I must do before using the p12 file?

I have previously (2 years back) purchased a p12 key from the same provider and that one did not have any issue. That key has expired now though.

Comment: This sounds familiar; and I thought it had something to do with a corrupted, or incorrectly created, certificate.  But, I'm not remembering details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After looking around I was able to generate a new P12 certificate which works. Yay!

The last answer in this Adobe forum worked:

http://forums.adobe.com/message/1975832#1975832

Here are the steps listed on the forum:

1. I get the certificate cert-client.p12 from my client
2. Double click and install the certificate from the windows explorer
3. Open Internetexplorer > Tools > Internet Options > Content > Certificates
4. Select the certificate which have previously imported and click export
5. Next
6. Yes, export the private key
7. Format: PKCS, (checked) Include all certificates in the... , (checked) Enable Strong protection, (unchecked) Delete the private key ...
8. Next
9. Enter Password for the certificate
10. Next enter filename and export the file
11. Rename the file to pk12

Comment: I used the following configuration (different for Windows 8, I think):

* Include all certificates in the certification path if possible: YES
* Delete the private key: NO
* Export all extended properties: NO

Comment: A few important things to keep in mind too; if you converted a `.cer` to a `.pfx` or `.p12` using OpenSSL, make sure to **run as administrator**. It will still generate a certificate otherwise but it won't work.

Comment: Can someone update the answer to explain what this is actually doing?  It worked for me, but I'm not sure why.